# How to install pypdfocr?

Tags: python, ocr

While trying to install pypdfocr package in python am getting below error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\GIBIN_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uansf_7f\\evernote\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\U
sers\\GIBIN_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uansf_7f\\evernote\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base
 pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\GIBIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uansf_7f\evernote\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\GIBIN_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uansf_7f\evernote\setup.py", line 6
        exec x
             ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the `PyPDFOCR` project on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pypdfocr/) is not set up with any version restrictions, it lists `evernote` as a requirement. If you look at your error message, you will notice that it is actually this installation that is causing issues. This is not suprising, as looking at the [github page for evernote](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python) reveals:

> Evernote API version 1.28
>
> This SDK is intended for use with Python 2.X
>
> For Evernote's beta Python 3 SDK see https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python3

So the requirement `evernote` cannot be installed for your python version (3.7), but you could try it using the `python3` version, which is called [evernote3](https://pypi.org/project/evernote3/) on pypi. To do this, I recommend the following steps:

1. Download [pypdfocr-0.9.1.tar.gz from pypi](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/23/1bf42cb12af63d498fcd425882815c21efef37800514dbad9fa28918df5e/pypdfocr-0.9.1.tar.gz)
2. Extract the tar.gz and manually change `evernote` to `evernote3` in the `requirements.txt`
3. Run `python setup.py install`

This should download and install `evernote3` as a requirement and then continue with the installation of `PyPDFOCR`.

This might fail however if the `evernote3` API is different than the `evernote` API or if other parts of `PyPDFOCR` depent on `python2` in which case you will have to do more manula tweaking or use a virtual environment with `python2`

Of course you could also search for another library that is more up to date and serves your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, avoid using the `python setup.py install` command. It is preferable to use the `pip install .` command instead.

so, after step2 of @FlyingTeller's answer run `pip install .`

With `python setup.py install` approach, you may encounter problems while removing a package. All of the files that were installed this way must be removed manually.